# Suggestions for improving the moderator flag overlay view

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

I find the flag overlays to be really useful when reviewing flags but I think that they could use some finessing.

The two main points for improvement I suggest are:

1. When there are lots of flags on a post and the overlay is at its tallest, it obscures a lot of the page on my laptop screen, rendering the page difficult to actually moderate on. Along with this, the option to "close" the overlay gets rid of it completely and requires refreshing the page to bring it back.
2. The overlay forces mods to be mods first rather than giving us a chance to be normal users... there's no way to make the "closed" status sticky while browsing so when you're on a site that gets a lot of flags, many posts bug you to act, often on stuff you're choosing *not* to act on immediately.

Here's what it looks like (actual flags obscured):

[image: Flag overlay for moderators with annotations of features]

For reference: my laptop screen is 900 px high (2011 15 inch MBP). It seems like the overlay is fixed to a max height of about 415 px (purple bar). That means the red bar is whatever space *isn't* used up by:

- the menu bar (not shown),
- browser tabs
- browser toolbar
- other stuff?

This leaves (in my case) *less* than 415 px - about 400 px - for the actual page content.

---

How can this be fixed? For item one, I can think of a couple of options, both are giving us the option to minimize/collapse/resize the overlay:

- Replace "close" with "minimize" or "▼". Clicking on this would reduce the height of the overlay to about the same height as the top bar (~40-50 px) and it would show only the forward and back arrows and "open" or "▲" to reopen the overlay. Something like this:

[image: Example of how collapsed overlay would look]

- Make it possible to resize the overlay (grab and drag the top up and down) so that mods can choose how tall it is with a minimum height that would snap to Something similar to the option above.

You could implement both of these together, too... though that may be a bit much... but useful.

Now, making the browser **remember** the setting last used for this (open/collapsed/specifically sized) would make item two possible without having to have a setting for it. I really enjoy moderating the sites I'm a moderator on but sometimes it'd be nice to just turn off the moderation features so that I can focus on actually using the site... I can't imagine what it's like for staff who have diamonds everywhere on the network.

I wouldn't mind a 50 px bar on the bottom of the screen that indicates there are flags on a question *without* showing me the flags. If I want to look at them, I can see they're there and investigate but it's possible I might not notice them at all if I'm just trying to use the site.

---

If this is scriptable, I'll take that, too. I know this probably wouldn't be a high priority request.

Comment: This has inspired me to make some long-ignored changes to my mod tools user script, but unfortunately I didn't actually finish it before I needed to go to bed despite being fueled by several cans of Pibb Xtra. Will finish tomorrow. (Hint: I'd get rid of that overlay. It's ugly and I hate it and I'm sure it hates me too.)

Comment: A related issue is that old flags, flags that have already been dealt with in the past (even years ago) are shown in the overlay and that can be confusing. I remember seeing a flag and then spending quite a bit of time trying to find it and deal with it before realizing it was an old one. Granted, I was a new mod then, but it might be worth hiding obsolete flags unless the mod chooses to see them.

Answer (score 9):

I don't like the idea of a collapsible / resizeable bar; when you *are* handling flags, it's important to have all the relevant information handy - having to go look for it (or worse, seeing *some* of it and thinking you've seen everything) just increases the chance of a mistake.

Part of the problem is that we're dividing the information into two sections and *completely segregating them*: post / comment information on the top, flag information on the bottom. This forces you to constantly match up relevant information in the two sections... And ignore irrelevant information, which tends to be plentiful in both.

### A table of issues

For this reason, [Monica's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305984/suggestions-for-improving-the-moderator-flag-overlay-view/305987#305987) caught my eye immediately: what she's describing is essentially a *table of contents* for issues on the page... Rather than dumping all the flag information into one big pile, it summarizes and groups it by post.

There's one big problem with Monica's idea: to actually *do anything* it requires you to dismiss the birds-eye view and go back to the *wall of flags*.

### A Jin Tonic

It probably doesn't surprise you to learn that we've been discussing this problem for *a long time*... Back when waffles designed that flag bar, we didn't have nearly the volume or complexity of flagging situations; there certainly weren't posts with dozens of historical flags going back years to clutter up the view. So in the spring of 2014, Jarrod & Jin teamed up to design something better; they never got the chance to finish it, but I loved the prototype so much that I've been using it almost constantly for the past 4 years. It looked like this:

[image: mock-up of flags shown inline with posts and comments]

By showing the flags inline, each positioned *right below* the relevant post or comment, the "matching game" aspect of flag handling is removed: you need not search for the flag for a post or the post for a flag - they will always be adjacent!

There was one big flaw with this though: *how do you **find** the flags in a long page full of answers and comments?* This gets pretty annoying even on a page with only a couple of answers; [this question over on Code Golf currently has flags on three posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/simple-cat-program) - good luck finding them across the *nine pages* of answers (hint: none of them are on the first page).

### Two great tastes that taste great together

When I saw Monica's table-of-contents idea, I immediately thought: this is a perfect match for the inline flag design!

So I threw together a quick and dirty prototype and started playing with it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think the combination is a *significant* improvement over what we have today.

### Downsides of this approach

It ain't all roses though. There are a couple of fairly significant deficiencies to this approach:

1. **Stuff moves** around the page - this makes it hard to develop effective muscle-memory for common actions like deleting comments or dismissing flags.
2. **It doesn't slap you in the face** - that big ol' flag bar kinda *demanded* that flags get handled; ignoring it was pretty near impossible. The svelt ToC and occasional inline flags are... Pretty easy to overlook.

Comment: Elsewhere on Meta I've bemoaned the lack of inline flag info for comments (show 37 comments, 8 of them are flagged, good luck!), but I hadn't thought of combining inline flags with the table of contents.  This prototype has made handling flags much easier for me.

Comment: This really does a great job of cleaning up the page and making flag handling easy. I really like how it looks. Being able to see comment flags right next to the comments makes things a lot easier. I'd seen a version of Jin's and I really liked it but couldn't really use it because finding flags even when there are only 10 answers was difficult because there was no way to anchor to them on the page. This solves that really nicely. Now I just need a way to demod myself temporarily. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to have the option for a compact view, so I can see that there are flags but they don't take up most of the height.  I'd also like to be able to easily see *what* is flagged (which answers, where are the comment-flag piles) without scrolling through all the details.  I propose a middle option, between the full view and completely banished, that looks something like this:

[image: compact view]

(Please forgive my uneven freehand flag graphemes.)

The view would show as many flag piles as could be laid out in one row, starting with the question and then showing answers in priority order (red flags, then highest flag counts first).  In this example, the answer from JoeBlow was flagged *and* it has 14 flagged comments.  The answer from Jon Skeet was not flagged but it has three flagged comments.  If this isn't everything, you get some text ("more flags") to tell you the bad news.  The existing close button is joined by an "expand" button to take you to the current view.  (The current view gets a "collapse" button.)  There are no scroll bars, either vertical or horizontal; it's not trying to show everything.

I put the question first even if it doesn't have the worst flags because addressing a problem with a *question* can affect how, or whether, you handle problems with answers.  But if this is confusing, "most severe first" (regardless of post type) would be fine too.

Long user names could really mess this up.  Maybe names get truncated at some reasonable length.  Only moderators (and employees) will see this, so if user3141592653589793238462643383279502884197's name gets shortened to something manageable but still recognizable, his public name hasn't been damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem today, and was a little less fortunate than you, as the flag overlay completely blocked the post, as seen in below screenshot:

[image: Flag overlay blocking the post]

I was wondering if we could use a layout like the browser toolbox, as shown in screenshot further down.

- **The site header can be hidden in mod mode**: It wastes way too much real estate in *normal* mode anyway, and a moderator has no good reason to "Ask Question" or do any of the other cool stuff found on that bar while reviewing flags. A small size icon and/or site name in smaller font can be placed somewhere on the page as an easy visual hint (especially for multi-site moderators).
- **The flag "overlay" can be placed separately at the bottom**: The flag "overlay" frame can be resizable. The "main" page and the "overlay" frame can be scrollable separately.

[image: Move flag overlay to a separate frame like browser toolbox]

Comment: Over the next few months the header bar on every site will be cut in half (height-wise) and those links moved to the left sidebar.

Comment: If the "upgrade" on SO is any indication, that new layout is still going to result in a massive real estate waste, besides it won't solve this overlay problem.