# The moderator flag overlay obscures too much of the screen, can't see the content on smaller screen heights

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

Quite literally: I cannot see it.

[image: A big, big block of flags at the bottom of the screen, occluding 'most everything.]

The old system was annoying in this respect, but this is *ridiculous*! I can't even see the full sidebar at once! This new interface is very, very big, and there should be a smaller y-height set on it to compensate.

Could the y-height be set proportionally to the size of the screen, or could you give us the ability to shrink it?

Comment: I'm hesitant to dupe this but I think it's pretty much the same as my question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305984/suggestions-for-improving-the-moderator-flag-overlay-view

Comment: @Catija Yeah, I think it is a duplicate too. However, it's slightly more of a problem now, since it used to take 3 or 4 flags to cause the issue, instead of just two.

Comment: Yup, agreed. I'm hoping that we'll be able to actually change the waffle bar more drastically but a "minimize" button might be the easy, early win here.

Comment: Workaround: if you have the ability to run userscripts, try the [flag TOC script](https://github.com/Shog9/flagtools) that Shog wrote in response to me (and others) complaining about this.  I thought they were going to actually bake that in for everybody, but it hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue even on my pretty good sized screens with a single flag active ... I can't even hit the button on the mod message dialog for the flag banner being in the way.

[image]

Comment: That's a z-index problem... the modal should be above the waffle bar. A bunch of our z-indexes got mucked up recently. 